# Как распарсить JSON PHP?

Tags: php, json

Имеется такая строка (после json_decode):

```
{"data1":{"261563":"Руководители 2-го уровня центрального офиса"},"data2":{"261494":"Заместитель HR директора по делопроизводству"},"data3":{"261474":["261565"],"261475":["261564","267412","261565"],"261476":["267414","267411","267409","261563","261564","267412","267413"]},"data4":7}
```

Как отсюда получить data1, data2 и т.д.?

```
$data = normJsonStr(json_decode($_POST['data']));

$json_str = json_decode($data, true);
$data1 = $json_str['data1'];

$fc = fopen(__DIR__ . "/positions.txt", "a");
fwrite($fc, $data1); //пусто
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85453/discussion-on-question-by----json-php).

Answer (score 3):

Как у тебя может получиться такая строка после json_decode ?
Ты просто json строку привёл.
Вообще берёшь эту строку и загоняешь её в json_decode()

```
$data = json_decode($json_str, true);
$data1 = $data['data1'];
//и т.д.
```

Comment: Так пробовал, в переменной пусто

Comment: @Сергей тут `$json_str` это `$_POST['data']`. А вы наверно пробовали со своим `$json_str = json_decode($data, true);`?

Comment: @Сергей если в переменной пусто, то после json_decode используйте json_last_error() (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-last-error.php), чтоб наверняка понимать что не так с вашим json-ом.